# What Configuration Values are available for Google Cloud VPN using IKE v1?

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, ipsec

My client is asking me to fill out a form in order to setup the VPN and make sure that our configuration values are compatible. They've sent me a list of configuration values for the VPN using IKE v1 that they use, such as

- Mode
- Encryption Algorithm for Phase 1
- Hashing Algorithm
- Diffie-Hellman Group
- .....

I've setup these variables in a previous VPN using ipsec on CentOS, but on Google Cloud VPN I haven't found anything related to this. The documentation doesn't mention that you could configure these values, nor it says which values does it use on its own. So, how could I know which values are supported on Google Cloud VPN in order to make sure they are compatible to what my client is requesting from us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the desire configuration here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/advanced#supported_ike_ciphers

Comment: Thanks! One quick question, where did you find that link?